# How do you say that a food and a sauce 'harmonize'?

Tags: expressions, food

One time I told my friend that I ate a piece of bread with honey (not jam, real honey from the bottle) and my friend asked me if the honey is good with bread.

Sometimes you say to two people (usually they are a couple)
"You two look good together"

In a similar way, I wanted to say something like 
"Honey and bread are good together". The problem with this is, I think the bread is the main element and honey is like a sub-element. But here, they seem to be in the same rank/position:

"Honey is pretty good on bread"
"Honey is good with bread"

Is there any common expression for this?

Comment: By the way...the best honey is not "from the bottle", but from the comb ;)

Answer (score 4):

You might want to say *"Honey **complements** bread"*.

That's a rather odd pairing (everyone to their own taste!). But Brits, for example, say things like...

> [[Mint sauce/jelly] complements roast lamb.](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22mint%20sauce%20complements%20roast%20lamb%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22complements%20roast%20lamb%22&oq=%22complements%20roast%20lamb%22&gs_l=serp.3...3305.4917.0.5775.11.9.0.0.0.2.204.981.6j2j1.9.0...0.0...1c.1.duQ7SnSmEfE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=cd2c56685dba42a2&bpcl=38093640&biw=1223&bih=893)

Comment: Hmmm, that is interesting.. I like the way brits say though haha, and yes, this is odd pairing, but try it, you will experience the new world.. if you get bored with nutella

Comment: @Johnny Koo: [The sweetness of the Nutella complements the saltiness of the cheese perfectly.](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22mint+sauce+complements+roast+lamb%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&gs_nf=3&tok=-ns4dPVkfS0nXTCJ-95lgw&ds=bo&pq=%22complements%20roast%20lamb%22&cp=21&gs_id=63&xhr=t&q=%22nutella+complements%22&pf=p&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&oq=%22nutella+complements%22&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=cd2c56685dba42a2&bpcl=38093640&biw=1223&bih=893) :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - EWWWW!

Answer (score 3):

You can say "the honey **complements** the bread", or "the honey **goes well with** the bread". **Harmonizes** as you say in your title is not bad either.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful expressions Mark, now I can tell my girlfriend more expressions! so awesome !!!!

Comment: Similarly, people often just say two foods **go together** or one food simply **goes with** the other.  "Fried catfish and cheese grits go together"  "Everyone knows that milk goes with cookies" etc.

Answer (score 0):

Informally, in the UK, you could say X and Y 'go well together', or 'go really well together' as in the case of Nutella and cheese (if you're @FumbleFingers)

Comment: My post was over a year ago, at which time it was just a fluke that I found that particular pairing with Johnny's ***nutella***. I didn't even think about what it might actually *taste* like, and had no experience of anything remotely similar. Since then, entirely unrelatedly, I've had my first introductions to *apply pie + cheddar cheese (the kind with [crystals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheese_crystals))* and *peanut butter (the kind that's crunchy) + jam (the kind Americans call [jelly](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35809/))*. Both ***fabulous!***