# "jam," "jelly," and "jello" in AmEng vernacular

Tags: american-english, word-usage, dialects, colloquialisms, disambiguities

What exactly is the fruit preserve called "jam" in the U.S.?

Is it what is referred to in France as "confiture"?

If so, then what would be the French for,

- what is called "jelly" in the U.S. ("jam" in the UK)-
- what is called "jello" in the U.S. ("jelly" in the UK)-

In other words, what would the average American commonly call the [**"confiture" and "gelée" preserves**](http://www.androsrestauration.fr/extension/isandros/files/ft_confitures.pdf) typically found for breakfast in every French hotel?

- "jam" and "jelly"?
- "[**preserve**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=preserves%20and%20jellies%2Cjellies%20and%20preserves%2Cjams%20and%20preserves%2Cpreserves%20and%20jams&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpreserves%20and%20jellies%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjellies%20and%20preserves%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjams%20and%20preserves%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpreserves%20and%20jams%3B%2Cc0)" and "jelly"?
- "jelly" and "jello"?
- "jelly" and "gelatin"?
- something else?

> [Fiches pratiques confitures, gelées, marmelades de fruits et produits similaires](http://www.economie.gouv.fr/dgccrf/Publications/Vie-pratique/Fiches-pratiques/Confitures-gelees-marmelades-de-fruits)
>
> [Google Pictures confiture de fraises](https://www.google.fr/search?q=confiture%20de%20fraise&biw=653&bih=429&prmd=ivsn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJzp3R7pzKAhVBIg8KHefXDTgQ_AUIBigB#tbm=isch&q=confiture%20de%20fraises)
>
> [Google Pictures confiture de groseilles](https://www.google.fr/search?biw=1024&bih=672&noj=1&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=w2-RVpSZJIn5UoyOt_gE&q=%22confiture%20de%20groseilles%22&btnG=)
>
> [Google Pictures gelée de fraises](https://www.google.fr/search?q=confiture%20de%20fraise&biw=653&bih=429&prmd=ivsn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJzp3R7pzKAhVBIg8KHefXDTgQ_AUIBigB#tbm=isch&q=gelee%20de%20fraises)
>
> [Google Pictures gelée de groseilles](https://www.google.fr/search?biw=1024&bih=672&noj=1&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=w2-RVpSZJIn5UoyOt_gE&q=%22gel%C3%A9e%20de%20groseilles%22&btnG=)
>
> [Ngram AmEng 2009](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=strawberry%20jam%2Cstrawberry%20jelly%2Cstrawberry%20jello&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstrawberry%20jam%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstrawberry%20jelly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstrawberry%20jello%3B%2Cc0);%20[Ngram%20AmEng%202009%20doughnut](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jam%20doughnut%2Cjelly%20doughnut%2Cjelly%20donut&year_start=1985&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjam%20doughnut%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjelly%20doughnut%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjelly%20donut%3B%2Cc0)
>
> [Ngram BrEng 2009](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=strawberry%20jam%2Cstrawberry%20jelly%2Cstrawberry%20jello&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstrawberry%20jam%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstrawberry%20jelly%3B%2Cc0);%20[Ngram%20BrEng%202009%20doughnut](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jam%20doughnut%2Cjelly%20doughnut%2Cjelly%20donut&year_start=1985&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjam%20doughnut%3B%2Cc0)
>
> **Videos**:
>
> [Red currant "gelée"](http://cuisine.journaldesfemmes.com/recette/317910-gelee-de-groseilles)
>
> [Strawberry "confiture"](http://cuisine.journaldesfemmes.com/recette/313384-confiture-de-fraises)

**jam**:

> a food made by boiling fruit and sugar to a thick consistency [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jam)
>
> *n* (*to eat*) confiture *f*
>
> strawberry jam *la confiture de fraises* [Collins English-French Dictionary](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/jam)
>
> In English *marmalade* refers only to a food made from oranges, lemons, limes, or grapefruit. Don't use it to refer to a similar food made from other fruits, for example blackberries, strawberries, or apricots. A food like this is called *jam* in British English, and ***jam or jelly*** in American English. *I bought a jar of raspberry jam*. *She made us jelly sandwiches*. (Collins COBUILD English Usage © HarperCollins Publishers, Ed. 2012)

**jelly**:

> a soft somewhat elastic food product made usually with gelatin or pectin; especially :  a fruit product made by boiling sugar and the juice of fruit [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jelly)
>
> *n* (=dessert)   gelée    *f*
>
> → *In the middle of the table stood a large bowl of jelly*.
>
> (*US*)   (=jam)   confiture    *f*
>
> → *I had two peanut butter and jelly sandwiches*. [Collins English-French Dictionary](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/jelly)

**preserve**:

> fruit canned or made into jams or jellies or cooked whole or in large pieces in a syrup so as to keep its shape; *a jar of strawberry preserve* [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jelly)
>
> *n* (=*jam*) confiture *f*
>
> → *Brush top of pudding with apricot preserve or honey*.
>
> → *The store cupboard was full of preserves*.
>
> → *a plate of butter and a jar of rhubarb preserves*.
>
> → *strawberry preserve*
>
> a spiced cranberry preserve to go with the turkey  *de la confiture de canneberges épicée pour aller avec la dinde* [Collins English-French Dictionary](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/preserve)

**jello**:

> *Trademark.* a brand of dessert made from a mixture of gelatin, sugar, and fruit flavoring, dissolved in hot water and chilled until firm. Random House
>
> *n* (*US*) (=jelly) gelée *f*  [Collins English-French Dictionary](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/jell-O)
>
> jello/jelly/gelatin (AmEng/BrEng) [WordReference Discussion](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/jell-o-jelly-gelatin-ae-be.2710291/page-2)

**gelatin**:

> an edible jelly made with gelatin [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gelatin)

Comment: As I understand it, *jelly* is strained, while *jam* is not. *Marmalade* is made from citrus fruits, including the peel. It might help if you explained the different between *confiture, confiture extra, gelée,* and *marmelade* in French, since there is no such thing as *strawberry marmalade* in English.

Comment: Does 'conserve' need to be included too?

Comment: I think Americans just use two labels while you use three. American: *jam* and *jelly*. French: *confiture extra, confiture, gelée*.

Comment: Jam has fruit in it, jelly doesn't.

Comment: @PeterShor Thing is, some French-English dictionaries mark "jelly" as the AmEng equivalent of what is called "jam" by the Brits ("confiture" in French.) Then, what's the AmEng for French "gelée"?

Comment: These dictionaries are technically wrong (although many Americans use the word *"jelly"* for both *"jam"* and *"jelly"*): *confiture* is *jam* and *gelée* is *jelly*, and I think the law says they have to be sold under the correct name. I'm sure you can buy *confiture extra*, but we don't have a special word for it; it would be sold as jam.

Comment: @PeterShor WordReference marks "jar of jelly" as the AmEng for BrEng "jar of jam"... http://www.wordreference.com/fren/confiture; http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/jelly

Comment: I think WordReference got confused by the difference between British English and American English. In British English, it appears that *confiture* and *gelée* are both *"jam"*. In the U.S., technically *confiture* is *"jam"* and *gelée* is *"jelly"*. However, a lot of Americans treat *jam* and *jelly* as synonyms. And what is called *jelly* in the U.K. is called *jello* in the U.S. (from the brand name, although it's usually treated as a generic term now).

Comment: H B Casimir's essay _When does Jam Become Marmalade?_ in the wonderful [A Random Walk in Science](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=UGGhM2XKE_0C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) is about how the British make a distinction between "jam" and "marmalade" that is nearly incomprehensible to foreigners. Well, it's actually about how the British make a distinction between "science" and other branches of learning which is hard to make in German or Dutch; but jam/marmalade is the vehicle for his point.

Comment: @PeterShor Oh, yeah?  Have you tried this:  http://www.epicurious.com/recipes/food/views/fresh-strawberry-marmalade-5386 ? It sounds disgusting, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: The [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/jelly) get it wrong, too. So maybe that's where WordReference got their definition from.

Comment: Closely related: [What's the difference between “jelly” and “jam”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35809/whats-the-difference-between-jelly-and-jam)

Comment: @PeterShor Per Wikipedia, "jelly" would be the US equivalent of what is called "jam" in the UK, that is, a general term for any type of fruit preserve. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit_preserves#Regional_terminology

Comment: @Christopher do you mean 'preserves' (the common alternative in this subject area)?

Comment: In AmE, there are a number of fruity bread spreads: jelly (thick clear fruit spread), jam (thick fruit spread with pieces of fruit), preserves (really thick jam with lots of fruit). In AmE, Jello is not in that set (it is something you eat entirely by itself).

Comment: Your definitions are correct, so I don't see what the question is about.  Jam is a spread made from whole fruit (absent pits and peels, of course).  Jelly is a spread made only from the juice.  Jam is sort of pasty/oozy, while jelly is relatively solid and can, eg, if one is careful, be cut into cubes (though is spreads easily on toast).  Jello is a trademark for a gelatin dessert which resembles jelly in consistency, only a bit stiffer.

Comment: For translation questions, you can't just say 'what is the word for this in English?' because that presumes great understanding of the nuances of the original (here French). You need to give lots of description (in English) of the meaning and use of the original (the French term). We also have to be aware of the meanings of these terms in very different contexts. e.g. in AmE, 'jam' can be a 'synonym' of 'smash', 'jelly' can be anything gelatinous, and 'preserve' can be a protected nature area, out of many possibilities.

Comment: @HotLicks Elian wants to know what French terms the British and American terms correspond to.

Comment: @Mitch - Well then, he needs to compare to the French definitions.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes. I agree.

Comment: Is this on topic? If it's about the English terms corresponding to certain French words, surely French.SE would be a better place to ask?

Comment: It's still unclear what your question is.  The definitions you had for "jam" and "jelly" have been confirmed, and you (who presumably speak French) are a better judge than most of us as to whether those definitions match the French terms you're looking at.

Comment: @Mitch, no I mean [conserve](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conserve) definition #2, better definition in [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/conserve) #4

Comment: @Mitch one of the French translations of confiture is conserve

Comment: @Christopher Indeed. We say, "Je vais faire des confitures pour l'hiver" (I'm gonna make some preserves/conserves for the winter). However, "Comment faire de la confiture de fraises" equals "How to make strawberry jam."

Comment: @Elian and for completeness 'compote' needs to be included too.

Comment: @Christopher "compote" in France is fruit (usually apple or any other fruit with an apple base) stewed or cooked with sugar and served as a dessert.

Comment: @Christopher Apparently, some people in the US say "jelly" for what is actually "jam," sort of like "geleia" is what some Brazilians call the fruit spread that is referred to as "doce" (=jam) in Portugal...

Comment: @Christopher re 'conserve': both those dictionary definitions are for _verbs_ and we are talking entirely about _nouns_ (also for myself I've never heard of 'conserving' directly meaning 'preserving fruit like in jam'.  The noun definition #5 in dictionary.com is  'conserves' (the plural) and it sounds to me like 'preserves' but I've never heard that word like that before. So as much as you may trust online English dictionaries and your French English dictionary, they are way off for me.

Comment: @Mitch OED lists four definitions for conserve as a noun, is the OED sufficiently trustworthy for you? Which 'free' online dictionaries can I use for definitions on EL&U?

Comment: @Christopher 1) OED is the most trustworthy and also tends to give more precise nuances. This is old news so I'm having trouble reconstructing all the context and references, but I'm just telling you my personal (but not inexperienced) opinions on the words (and dictionaries, and entries) in question.

Comment: @Christopher  2) You can use _any_ dictionary you like as long as you quote the appropriate parts (and give a link and tell us the source) so that we can look and judge for ourselves. I personally find the OED is the best (but is paywalled (but you can access through local libraries)), M-W next best (but just for AmE), Collins, ODO (which is not OED), Cambridge, Free Dictionary, a lot lower, and with a gun to my head _maybe_ Wiktionary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What *exactly* is the fruit preserve called "jam" in the U.S?
>    [my emphasis]

I'm answering the question from the point of view of language, what these words mean to the speakers who use them. Thus, many speakers might call a fruit spread in a dish *jam* or *jelly* based on regional preferences rather than on the actual recipe.

Many foods on the American supermarket shelf are not what their labels say they are, so many Americans could not tell you the difference between jam and jelly, only that they tend to use the one or the other word.  For many speakers, these words refer to a sweet spread,  gelatinous in texture, that seems to be fruit-based (grape, blackberry, blueberry, strawberry, etc) though it may contain no fruit only fruit-juice, or no real fruit product at all, merely some artificial fruit flavoring and coloring.

Jello is a tradename for a rubbery (artificial) fruit-flavored gelatin.

Here's the federal definition per [Consumer Reports](http://www.consumerreports.org/cro/magazine/2013/01/spread-it-on-best-jellies-and-jams/index.htm) in a little blurb about the differences, and that's usually a good indication that many people don't know the difference. **spreadable fruit** and **fruit spread** are terms without federal definition.

Comment: The labels on jams and jellies actually are supposed to follow the federal definition. And I suspect they do. However, it's quite possible that food companies have figured out how to label something as *"jam"* when it really looks and tastes more like jelly.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a-bfeyYuj3o

Comment: I think if you actually look in the average grocery store you will find the definitions of "jam", "jelly", and "marmalade" are fairly closely adhered to in the labeling of products.  (That Youtube link is simply advertising hype.  Most people would instantly recognize the stuff being spooned from the jar as "jam".)

Comment: I think the commercial reveals a linguistic fact, that for a good many people, the sweet spreadable stuff is jam and for a good many, it's jelly, regardless of what it actually is.

Comment: +1 specifically for `many Americans could not tell you the difference between jam and jelly`

Comment: @Daenyth what is his proof that Americans can't tell the difference or wouldn't know?

Comment: @TimRomano The commercial doesn't prove anything...nothing about what real people think.

Comment: @michael_timofeev Per Wikipedia, "jelly" in the U.S. is used as a general term for any type of fruit preserve, while in the UK "jam" is the preferred term. This would explain why some bilingual dictionaries give "jelly" as the AmEng equivalent to BrEng "jam"... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit_preserves#Regional_terminology

Comment: How do you know that "jelly" is the "general term"?  Visiting at some breakfast tables some moms might ask "Do you want some jelly?", others might ask "Do you want some jam?", others might ask "Do you want some marmalade?"  My grandmother would say "marmalade", my mother "jam".

Comment: @Elian you really need to understand how diverse the US is, especially AmE, so your questions about "What is this equivalent to in AmE?" already start from a misconception that AmE is homogenous.  So people who authoritatively make declarations about AmE and how "we say it like this." are setting themselves up for "Oh, really?  Prove it to me."  I feel upset that some of my own "countrymen" say things like no one knows the difference.  Really?

Comment: @HotLicks this entire conversation about jam and jelly is one big romp in opinion land.  "No one knows the difference between jam or jelly." Really?

Comment: @michael_timofeev: One thing I really dislike is to have what I've  said distorted. Do I anywhere say "no one" in my answer?  No, I say "many speakers".

Comment: @TimRomano how much is "many speakers?"  I apologize for unintentionally distorting, but now we have Daenyth saying "could not..." which is close to can not...so this user seems to be making that leap also.  Plus I don't think it's fair to say that many foods are not what the labels say...that's complete nonsense...food has to have the ingredients approved and the contents listed.  Just between the two of us can you give me some products whose listed ingredients aren't in the product?

Comment: @TimRomano I'm sorry to upset you, but I think the answer is better without these statements.

Comment: @michael_timofeev: "Many" is a good deal fewer than everybody and a good deal more than no one. The US retail food industry has a long history of hoodwinking the consumer with misleading labeling.   http://www.brookings.edu/~/media/research/files/papers/2014/06/26-food-labeling-litigation/negowetti_food-labeling-litigation.pdf

Comment: @TimRomano http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/marmalade-jelly-jam-preserves-conserves.231764/; http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/jam-vs-jelly.1293166/

Answer (score 15):

You wrote, "In other words, what would Americans commonly call the "confiture" and "gelée" preserves typically found for breakfast in every French hotel?" The answer, taken from your choices, is "'jam' and 'jelly.'"

In America, jam includes the fruit in the mix; it is thicker, richer, and a bit lumpy in texture. It is spread on toasted bread that has been buttered first. It is also wonderful on vanilla ice cream. Jelly is used in the same way, but it is made from strained fruit and has uniform, smooth and "clear" texture, containing no lumps or pieces of the fruit from which it is made. Americans usually prefer one over the other, but many enjoy both. Jelly spreads more easily (as on a peanut butter sandwich), but jam offers more texture and flavor. We also enjoy marmalade, but use it less frequently and sometimes in different ways, for instance, as a complement to meats like pork.

Jello (tm) is a clear, colored gelatin dessert that is also used to make salads when combined with chunks of various canned fruits and/or marshmallows. In the latter case, it is often chilled and formed in a mold to give it a distinctive shape, with a scalloped top and a hole in the center, the same type of pan sometimes used to make a coffee cake or similar baked dessert. Jello comes in a box as a powder, to which one adds water and sugar while heating the mix. Once the liquid is uniform and clear, it is poured into a glass baking dish or pan and then placed in the refrigerator to chill into the firm, final dessert, which can be cut or spooned into individual servings.

Comment: Then, why do some French-English dictionaries mark "jelly" as the AmEng for what is referred to in the UK as "jam"? http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/jam

Comment: I don't know. However, I noticed that your reference missed a common usage in police jargon in the U. S.; to wit, "Jammed Up: To get a discipline from your superior officers, In other words to get in trouble; pay dock, C.D. ['Conditional Discharge'], suspension, termination..." from: policemag.com/cop-slang/jammed-up.aspx I realize this is irrelevant to the question at hand, but I found it interesting nevertheless.

Comment: @Elian British English doesn't really have the equivalent to American "jelly", (roughly jam without the fruit).  But since "jelly" in Br. Eng. refers to gelatine (Am. Eng. jello), you can really only translate Am Eng "jelly" into Br Eng "jam".  But I think most Americans distinguish the two in the way that Mark describes.

Comment: @MarkHubbard Although it's true that there is a quite technical term of 'marmelade' for certain types of additions to savory foods, isn't marmelade usually just jam made from citrus that includes the peel?  Or maybe 'marmelade' with this meaning is just Br Eng? (I'm a British/Canadian English speaker).

Comment: @AlanMunn, If there were room, I would paste in the complete quote starting with "The definition of marmalade has evolved over the centuries," but you can read it for yourself at this food-related site: http://homecooking.about.com/od/cookingfaqs/f/faqmarmalade.htm I found it much more interesting than any of the dictionary definitions I could find online. In short, you're correct. In most U. S. grocery stores, the only marmalade found on the shelves is usually "Orange Marmalade." Of course, specialty shops and online specialty-food sources will most likely include other variants as well.

Comment: *"Jelly spreads more easily (as on a peanut butter sandwich)"* funny, for me, I have the opposite opinion. I think Jam spreads much easily, especially on untoasted bread or on top of peanut butter. Spreading Jelly on toast is very workable, but I find it very difficult to spread Jelly on untoasted bread or PB (a bit like trying to "spread" Jello on anything), and usually it seems I am just pushing chunks of it around and end up cutting the Jelly it into small bits in order to help distribute it somewhat evenly. Overall though, a great answer.

Comment: @KevinFegan- Hahahaha! Well said! What does PB&J mean to you?

Comment: @AlanMunn I think marmalade also contains less sugar and can have a more tart flavor due to the inclusion of the peel. I grew up in a BrEng family and ended up loving jam and hating marmalade as a result.

Comment: @MarkHubbard I was very confused by a PB&J for a long time. I couldn't figure out why Americans put Jelly/Br (Jello/Am) on their sandwiches. It seemed very odd.

Comment: @stacey- Hahahaha! Another good one! Mrs. Hubbard just informed me that what I'm referring to as a traditional Jello mold is a "bundt cake pan" used for such purpose. As for those nay-sayers, most Americans are quite clear on the difference between "jelly" (strained or filtered then reduced fruit juice, pectin and sugar, with a translucent appearance) and "jam" ("a thick mixture of fruit, pectin, and sugar that is boiled gently but quickly until the fruit is soft and has an organic shape, yet is still thick enough that it spreads easily and can form a blob." http://tinyurl.com/jam-jelly-etc).

Answer (score 4):

Naming convention summary between British and American English.

```
+------------------+------------+------------+----------------------------------+------------------------------+
| American         | British    | French     | Description                      | Contains fruit (or juice)?   | 
+------------------+------------+------------+----------------------------------+------------------------------+
| Jello            | Jelly      | Gelée      | Gelatinous Dessert.              | Gelée yes, others no         |
| Jelly            | Jam        | Gelée      | Smooth fruit spread.             | Either fruit or fruit juice  | 
| Jam / Preserves  | Jam        | Confiture  | Fruit spread containing pieces.  | yes                          | 
| Marmalade        | Marmalade  | Marmelade  | Fruit spread containing peel.    | mostly citrus                | 
+------------------+------------+------------+----------------------------------+------------------------------+
* In general, the smooth fruit spread is slightly gelatinous.
```

It seems like the confusion lies between the American 'Jelly' and the British 'Jam'. I have tried both and the one i tried didn't have real juice and was artificially flavored, but some do have fruit juice.

Gelée seems to fall into the categories of the American Jello/Jelly and confiture is more the traditional British Jam.

Comment: The French for "marmalade" ("peel jam") is "marmelade"...

Comment: French "gelée," though, usually contains fruit in the form of juice (or aqueous extract) and pectine. http://www.bonnemaman.ch/fr/catalogue-confitures-c1.php#!category=2

Comment: @Elian i have revised the table. Jello is not particularly known to contain fruit juice.

Comment: Marmalade is used in the US, though probably less well known than the others.  (I suspect many in the US share my distaste for orange marmalade, the only kind readily available, but any grocery with a halfway complete set of such spreads will have marmalade.)

Comment: Also, it needs to be noted that (in the US) "jelly" is gelled -- it contains fruit pectins that make it ever so slightly rubbery (though not nearly as much as Jello).

Comment: And another detail:  "Preserves" is another (US) term for "jam".  Some people may make a distinction, but they are largely indistinguishable to the average person.

Comment: Nice systematic presentation!